# Control.Invoke() vs IProgress / ReportProgress

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, asynchronous

The UI can be passed information from an asynchronous task using `IProgress` or `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress`:

```
class Approach1 : UserControl
{
    enum Stage { INIT, STATUS, DATA, TIME, ... }
    struct ProgressObject
    {
         int StatusCode;
         int SecondsRemaining;
         IList<int> Data;
         Stage CurrentStage;
    }

    TextBox Status;

    async Task DoWork1(IProgress<ProgressObject> progress) 
    {
         await Task.Run( () =>
         {
             progress.Report(new ProgressObject(0, 0, null, Stage.INIT));
             int code = DoSomething();
             progress.Report(new ProgressObject(code, 0, null, Stage.STATUS));
             IList<int> Data = ...;
             progress.Report(new ProgressObject(0, 0, Data, Stage.DATA));
             int Seconds = ...;
             progress.Report(new ProgressObject(0, time, null, Stage.TIME));
         });
    }

    void ReportProgress(ProgressObject progress)
    {
        switch (progress.CurrentStage)
        {
            case Stage.CODE:
                Status.Text = DecodeStatus(progress.StatusCode);
                break;
            // And so forth...
        }
    }

    async void Caller1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var progress = new Progress<ProgressObject>(ReportProgress);
        await DoWork2(progress);
    }
}
```

However, this can also be done by passing a delegate to a UI object's `BeginInvoke` method (`Invoke` if we want to block):

```
class Approach2 : UserControl
{
    Textbox Status;

    int StatusCode
    {
        set
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action( () => Status.Text = DecodeStatus(value));
        }
    }

    // Imagine several other properties/methods like the above:
    int SecondsRemaining;
    void UpdateData(IList<int> data);

    async Task DoWork2()
    {
        await Task.Run( () =>
        {
            StatusCode = DoSomething();
            UpdateData(...);
            SecondsRemaining = ...;
        });
    }

    async void Caller2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await DoWork1();
    }
}
```

Should the dedicated progress reporting mechanisms be preferred over `Invoke`? If, so why? Are there any likely 'gotchas' arising from either approach?

IMHO, the `Invoke` way is simpler / requires less code compared to, say, a `ReportProgress` accepting a progress struct with several fields, especially if progress is reported at multiple stages of the task and the reporting method thus needs to branch to the appropriate reporting for a given stage.

Comment: The "question code" has naught to do with BeginInvoke vs Task.Run as they are both serving the same purpose. You might as well have written: `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => progress.Report(value));` to get a more fair comparison - in the first example the 'stuff to do' is done elsewhere.

Comment: I think you misunderstood - the question is about using `Invoke` vs. the framework's dedicated progress reporting features. In one case calling context is accessed using `Invoke`, in the other it is implicitly captured by `IProgress` implementation. Both examples use `Task.Run`.

Comment: Please make the code consistent, except where it should differ. Because the Task can be done without the ReportProgress/IProgress ("more code"), or the Invoke can be done with it.

Comment: I updated the example code to better reflect a real use case with complex progress reporting. This question is about which of two patterns accomplishing apparently identical results should be preferred, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have gotten a cue from your struggles to make Approach2 actually compile.  Took a while, didn't it?  I saw you repeatedly editing the snippet.  Another cue you got was that the only way to get there was to derive your class from UserControl.

Which is the problem with Begin/Invoke(), it can only work when you have access to a Control object.  Code inside a library often (and should) have no idea what the UI looks like.  It might not even be implemented in Winforms, could be used in a WPF or Universal app for example.

Progress<> works with those GUI class libraries as well, it uses a more universal way to properly synchronize.  Provided by the SynchronizationContext.Current property, it relies on the GUI class library to install a provider.  The one that Winforms installs, WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext, automatically calls BeginInvoke() in its Post() method and Invoke() in its Send() method.  Also the mechanism that makes async/await code independent from the UI implementation.

There is one disadvantage to Progress<>, it can completely fail to get the job done in a very hard to diagnose way.  The object *must* be created by code that runs on the UI thread of an app.  If it is not then SynchronizationContext.Current doesn't have a value and the ProgressChanged event is going to fire on an arbitrary threadpool thread.  Kaboom if you try to update the UI with an event handler, you won't know why because the exception occurs in code that's far removed from the bug.

But sure, if you hardcode your class to derive from System.Windows.Forms.UserControl then you have little use for Progress<>.  Other than the feel-good feeling that you'll have less work to do when you ever port it to another GUI class library.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! In my real code I already did use UserControl; the pattern worked first try. Sounds like the first pattern has the major advantage that nothing needs to be changed if the work methods are moved into a library and callers are made to implement their own progress methods.